# create ftp user for vsftpd server to specific directory

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

I need to create ftp user for vsftpd server only to to be root as a specific directory (only to that account )

example `/var/www/abc should be the /(root) to test_user`

Answer (score 3):

Uncomment/Insert the following line in/to `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` file:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

and create your user with home folder is `/var/www/abc`:

```
useradd -d /var/www/abc -s /sbin/nologin test_user
```